# Prove $|x-c|<\delta \implies |x^2-c^2|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I would like to know if my $\epsilon-\delta$-proof of the following is correct. $c$ is given and I'm trying to show that $\forall e > 0, \exists d > 0$ so that:
$$
|x-c| < d \implies |x^2-c^2| < e
$$
First I expand the squares:
$$
|x-c| < d \implies |x-c||x+c| < e
$$
By using the triangle inequality on $|x-c|$ I bound $|x|$
$$
|x|-|c| \leq |x-c| \land |x-c|<d\implies |x|< d + |c|
$$
I then use the triangle inequality again on the $|x+c|$ factor
$$
|x+c| \leq |x| + |c| < d + 2|c|
$$
Putting the bounds together
$$
|x+c||x-c| < d(d+2|c|) = d^2 + 2d|c|
$$
I then set the upper bound equal to $e$ and solve for $d$:
$$
d^2 + 2d|c| = e \iff d = \sqrt{e+|c|^2} - |c|
$$
Since I found a $d$ as a function of $e$ and $c$, is my proof complete?

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument looks fine. Expect that:

1. You might want to check your $d$ is really positive.
2. Your last $\Leftrightarrow$ is wrong. A quadratic equation should have two solutions.

Comment: $\sqrt{e+|c|^2} > |c|$ so $d$ should always be greater than 0.